# how to join three tables on every time when model load

Tags: model, resource-model, join, custom-collection, join-table

I want to join three tables on every time when model load (for example on edit from page, on grid page in admin and detail page in front-end etc... ) in my custom module. can you please let me know where is best place to code for this (in model class, in resource class or collection class) and what function I should use for joining?

please help me to fix this.

Edited:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
                    <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mynamespace_mymodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_resource>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <table1>
                        <table>mynamespace_mymodule_table1</table>
                    </table1>
                    <table2>
                        <table>mynamespace_mymodule_table2</table>
                    </table2>                   
                    <table3>
                        <table>mynamespace_mymodule_table3</table>
                    </table3>                   
                </entities>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mynamespace_mymodule>
                    <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
                </mynamespace_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_Mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml</Mynamespace_Mymodule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

techguy4web,

In this case,you need make **one table primary table** and  using join function`[left join,Inner join]` on **Resource Model and Resource Model Collection class** relation `rest of two classes`.

### Add Tables into Model Collection :

You need to first work on collection class.Here,you need do add function `_afterLoad()` on  **collection class**,w using this function you can **mapping relation between there table**.

On Resource Class : **Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Mymodel_Collection**

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
$select= $this->getSelect();
$select->joinLeft(
    array('SecondTable'=>$this->getTable('yourmodel/secondtable')),
    'Maintable.key=SecondTable.key',
    array('*')
);

$select->joinLeft(
    array('3rdTable'=>$this->getTable('yourmodel/thirdatble')),
    'Maintable.key=3rdTable.key',
    array('*')
);
return parent::_afterLoad();
}
```

**afterLoad()** trigger a **perform a operations after collection load**.

### Add Three tables into model

On resource class you need add multiple table using **function _getLoadSelect()** on **Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Mymodel**

```
 protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
    {
        $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

        $select->join(
                array('SecondTable' => $this->getTable('yourmodel/secondtable')),
               'Maintable.key=SecondTable.key',
                array());

        $select->join(
                array('3rdTable' => $this->getTable('yourmodel/thirdatble')),
               'Maintable.key=3rdTable.key',
                array());

    return $select;
    }
```

If resource collection is not work then try  this code at collection.php

**Create two individual function.which is include  rest of function to collection.**

```
public function addSecondTable(){

$select= $this->getSelect();
$select->joinLeft(
        array('SecondTable'=>$this->getTable('yourmodel/SecondTable')),
        'Maintable.key=SecondTable.key',
        array('*')
    return $this;   
}

public function addThirdTable(){

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('3rdTable'=>$this->getTable('yourmodel/Thirdatble')),
    'Maintable.key=3rdTable.key',
    array('*'));
    return $this;   
}
```

**You can use:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mynamespace_mymodule/mymodule_collection');
$collection->addSecondTable()->addThirdTable();
```

Comment: Many thanks @amit-bera for quick & detailed response. it's really appreciated. But still I have an issue with this. I am not able get this joined collection  on grid in `_prepareCollection()` function. I am calling collection like this `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mynamespace_mymodule/mymodule_collection');` can you please help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Show config XML code

Comment: I have edited my question, please check

Comment: please remove afterload function.. check   collection  model is woring or not

Comment: I have tried to put `die()` in _afterLoad function. it's working, i mean that function called. but in grid query it's not showing joined query statement.

Comment: wait.i will check..